# Element implicitly has an 'any' type while type is explicitly set

Tags: typescript, sorting

I have a comparator function `sortBy` that is used to sort objects `T` by any specified string property to pass into the array.sort function: `arr.sort(sortBy)`

```
export const sortBy = <T>(property: string) : (a: T, b: T) => number => {
    return (a: T, b: T) => {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) return 1
        else if (a[property] > b[property]) return -1
        return 0
    }
}
```

But I receive these errors:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

The function works when setting `a` and `b` to `any`

```
export const sortBy = <T>(property: string) : (a: T, b: T) => number => {
    return (a: T, b: T) => {
        if ((a as any)[property] < (b as any)[property]) return 1
        else if ((a as any)[property] > (b as any)[property]) return -1
        return 0
    }
}
```

But this looks *absolutely ugly*.

`T` **is always a one dimensional object** but setting `sortBy = <T = Record<string, string>>(property: string)...` gives me the same errors.

I don't know of any other way to write this in a better way.

Are there any alternatives or a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind property and object to make sure that property exists in object.

**Option 1**

```js
export const sortBy =
    <Prop extends PropertyKey>(property: Prop) =>
        <Obj extends Record<Prop, unknown>>(a: Obj, b: Obj) => {
            if (a[property] < b[property]) return 1
            else if (a[property] > b[property]) return -1
            return 0
        }

sortBy('a')({ a: 42 }, { a: 43 }) // ok
sortBy('b')({ a: 42 }, { a: 43 }) // error
```

`Obj` extends `Record<Prop, unknown>`. As you might have noticed, `Prop` was infered at the beginning. Not TS knows that `Obj` should have `Prop` property

**Option 2**

```js
export const sortBy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>
    (a: T, b: T) =>
    (property: keyof T) => {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) return 1
        else if (a[property] > b[property]) return -1
        return 0
    }

sortBy({ a: 42 }, { a: 43 })('a') // ok
sortBy({ a: 42 }, { a: 43 })('b') // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAxrAdgZxVhiAhAT2QF5kAeAFWSkXAwBMtkAlcdeRineASwwBzADTIArhgDWGWAHcMAPgWgAkAAoAhgC5kVUQCMdVAJRllIddHixo4JER2TwRWADNdp0guQBvVSr53TQBtKxs7RCIAXUpkfVDrW3so03hwRDF4DGQARn9wABsscGRA5BCwpMiY73jKiOjU9MzsgFo8ixU0jKzkAAZVAF9QUDwkYjUfZG1kABYAJmRB0SmZ2YBmJeM1AHINHdMAekPkWElR-AnVnQWllembzcHtnf0D5GPaeGt4IA)

Now TS is aware that property `a` exists in your objects

Comment: I really like the second answer as its seems more elegant.